# MigLayout update size of cells based on percentage after window resize

Tags: java, jframe, miglayout

I am writing an application where I would like to have this layout

```
            45%                35%           10%   
    -----------------------------------------------
    |                   |                |         |
    |                   |                |         |
60% |                   |                |         |
    |                   |                |         |
    -------------------------------------|         |
    |                                    |         |
40% |                                    |         |
    |                                    |         |
    ------------------------------------------------
```

I construct the layout using MigLayout manager in this way

```
MigLayout ml = new MigLayout("debug",
            "10[45%!,fill]5[35%!,fill]10[20%!,fill]",
            "10[60%!,fill]5[40%!,fill]");

setLayout(ml);
add(panel1, "cell 0 0 1 1, grow");
add(panel1, "cell 1 0 1 1, grow");
add(panel3, "cell 2 0 1 2, grow");
add(panel4, "cell 0 1 2 1, grow");
```

The problem is that if I resize the window, the layout doesn't follow the new size. It just stays the same size.

How do I fix this so that the layout would be refreshed and get the size of the window?

Note that I want each panel to fill its cell as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLay extends JFrame {

    private MigLay() {
        super("Button Layout");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new MigLayout("debug",
            "10[45%!,fill]5[35%!,fill]10[20%!,fill]",
            "10[60%!,fill]5[40%!,fill]"));
        createPanels();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createPanels() {
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(), panel2 = new JPanel(), panel3 = new JPanel(), panel4 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Panel 1");
        panel1.add(label);

        label = new JLabel("Panel 2");
        panel2.add(label);

        label = new JLabel("Panel 3");
        panel3.add(label);

        label = new JLabel("Panel 4");
        panel4.add(label);

        add(panel1, "cell 0 0 1 1, grow");
        add(panel2, "cell 1 0 1 1, grow");
        add(panel3, "cell 2 0 1 2, grow");
        add(panel4, "cell 0 1 2 1, grow");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MigLay();
    }
}
```

Changes made: **1)** You called panel 1 twice, so I created a panel 2.
**2)** I created your layout in the `setLayout()` method.

If neither of these changes fixes your problem, the problem is not with the code you posted above but somewhere in your code.

Comment: I tried this and it works but I found out that I was using a very old implementation of MigLayout. Updating the layout library fixed it for me.